# Failed to Launch iOS Simulator in vs code

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am getting the following error when I run my code in vs code. I am getting the same error if I use an android simulator.

> Failed to launch iOS Simulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within
> 60 seconds

Comment: Is the emulator/simulator already opened? Try running on already opened ones. Other solution would be to run projects directly from android studio / xcode.

Comment: The emulator was already opened. I even tried to restart it, but it doesn't work. I am running a flutter app in vs code.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `flutter doctor` should tell you what could be wrong. Most probably, you're using an outdated version of Xcode. Also, the output of `flutter doctor` should include the currently supported Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error after I reinstalled xcode. I solved it in the following way.

1. GET iOS Simulator on [XCode > Settings > Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0ear.png)
2. Relaunch iOS Simulator

I think it was necessary to reinstall the ios simulator.